# The feet of three normals from a point to a parabola determine a triangle. Show that its centroid lies on the parabola's axis.

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> How to prove that the centroid of a triangle formed by three co-normal points lies on the axis of the parabola?

**Note:** "Co-normal points" are the feet of normals drawn from a point to the parabola.

Comment: Can you define co-normal for us please?

Comment: Co normal points are the feet of normals drawn from a point to the parabola

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, we can consider the equation of the Parabola to be $\displaystyle y^2=4ax\  \ \ \ (1)$

From [this](http://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-coordinate-geometry/normal-to-a-parabola.aspx), the eqaution of the normal at $P(am^2,-2am)$ is $y = mx – 2am – am^3\iff am^3+2a m+y-mx=0$

which is  a Cubic Equation in $m$ having three roots $m_1,m_2,m_3$(say)

Using [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), $\displaystyle m_1+m_2+m_3=-\frac0a=0$

So, the [ordinate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinate) of the centroid of the Triangle will be $\displaystyle\frac{-2a(m_1+m_2+m_3)}3=0$ hence, the centroid will lie on the $X$ axis which is evidently the axis of the Parabola $(1)$

Comment: Really nice, sir!!!